# How to configure SSL in Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, virtualhost

How to configure SSL in apache webserver for both frontend and backend of yii2 project having the same IP but different port numbers and DocumentRoot?

Below is how I have tried but it's only work for whatever `virtualHost block` I start with.

I am using `centOS 7`

in `ssl.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.12.125:443>
    ServerName test.mydomain.co.tz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tan_web/frontend/web
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/mail_tanesco_co_tz.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/test_tanesco_co_tz.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.12.125:443>
    ServerName test.mydomain.co.tz:8080
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tan_web/backend/web
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/mail_tanesco_co_tz.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/test_tanesco_co_tz.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

and in `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.12.125:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.co.tz
    ServerName test.mydomain.co.tz:80
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tan_web/frontend/web
    Redirect permanent / https://test.mydomain.co.tz/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.12.125:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.co.tz
    ServerName test.mydomain.co.tz:8080
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tan_web/backend/web
    Redirect permanent / https://test.mydomain.co.tz:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone to help, I have stacked here for some days. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in virtualhost, you should have a unique combination of ipaddress and port. for example in the second block, change it from 443 to 8443

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.12.125:443>
    ServerName test.mydomain.co.tz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tan_web/frontend/web
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/mail_tanesco_co_tz.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/test_tanesco_co_tz.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.12.125:8443> <!-- Change the port here -->
    ServerName test.mydomain.co.tz:8080
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tan_web/backend/web
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/mail_tanesco_co_tz.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/test_tanesco_co_tz.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/tan_web/sslDocs/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

in httpd.conf,  the http traffic has to be directed to the relevant ports:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.12.125:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.co.tz
    ServerName test.mydomain.co.tz:80
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tan_web/frontend/web
    Redirect permanent / https://test.mydomain.co.tz/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.12.125:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.co.tz
    ServerName test.mydomain.co.tz:8080
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tan_web/backend/web
    Redirect permanent / https://test.mydomain.co.tz:8443/ <!-- Redirect to the new port -->
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please show the URL you use to call your backend

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS, add to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` and in Debian/Ubuntu at `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, the lines:

```
Listen 8080 https
```

Apache/mod_ssl, by default, 443/TCP is already known, but any others TLS aware TCP ports have to be added to the configuration.

Otherwise, any non 443/TCP port, will be handled only as an HTTP capable port.